# using stringify to send data through a socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

i am a little lost as to how to stringify this data.

if i send the following through the socket (from a knob movement, where v is our data):

```
  socket.send(synth.set("mySynth.freq", v));
```

then on receiving the data:

```
 socket.onmessage = function(evt){
console.log("synth from another browser " + evt.data);
    }
```

the console will log something to the effect of object Object. which tells me that i need to follow the instructions and encode my data in JSON. i just don't know how this works.

so, i believe it starts by sending:

```
var object;    
socket.send(JSON.stringify(object));
```

and then receiving

```
socket.onmessage = function(evt){
var object = JSON.parse(evt.data);
console.log("synth from another browser " + object);
    }
```

the code is sitting [here](https://github.com/mrtunes/websocket-relay-server/blob/master/web/synth.html).

Comment: If your console prints [Object object] it means you are sending a Javascript Object thought the web socket, you don't need to stringify it

Comment: I'm not sure.. the console should show him the object content, not just [object object].

Comment: @Nico not when you _add_ an object to a string. In that case, the object will be stringified to `[object Object]`. It should have been `console.log("synth from another browser ", evt.data)` (comma instead of plus)

Comment: @robertklep You are absolutely right !

Answer (score 0):

i did figure it out in the end.

```
//inside the knob handler
var synthobject = {"freq":v, "gate":"1"};     
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(synthobject);      
socket.send(jsonstring);


   //inside the socket section
 socket.onmessage = function(evt){
 var jsonobject = JSON.parse(evt.data);
 console.log("json import " + jsonobject.freq);
 synth.set("mySynth.freq", jsonobject.freq);
         }
```